# How can I install matlab Ubuntu 18.04. (./install fail)

Tags: matlab

descargue dos imagen iso de matlab, pero cuando lanzo ./install en la terminal me aparece este error: [./install: 1: exec: /home/sergio/Descargas/Matlab r2016b/Mathworks Matlab R2016b Linux/R2016b_glnxa64_dvd1/bin/glnxa64/install_unix: Exec format error]

[image]

Comment: I already did with sudo, but I have the same results

Comment: Are you trying to install it on a 32-bit system?

Comment: As I said on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53862203/how-can-i-install-matlab-ubuntu-18-04-install-fail), this is a pirated copy of MATLAB, please don’t try to get people to unknowingly break the law by helping you with this. MATLAB is not distributed with ISOs you download.

Comment: https://karibe.co.ke/2018/11/installing-matlab-2018a-from-two-iso-images-in-ubuntu-18-04/